# Not getting the optimal value of minimization problem and empty plots

Tags: matlab, optimization, gradient-descent, nonlinear-optimization

To solve the minimization problem using the gradient method with exact line search, the tolerance parameter = 10^-5 and initial vector x0= (2,1)^t:

> min x^2+y^2

I attempted to execute a Matlab code, but it seems to keep running indefinitely without ending. I am not getting the optimal value, which is

```
x =
1.0e-005 *
0.1254
-0.0627.
```

On one occasion, I was able to accidentally generate a figure when I tried to plot the gradient method's iterates along with the function's contour lines. Although I got the contour plot, there were no iterates to show the pathway down to the optimal solution. I included both my graph and the correct one from a book I am following to learn more about this topic.

**The first image is the correct figure from the book and the second one is what I finished coding.

Here is the code:

```
function [x,fun_val]=gradient_method_quadratic(A,b,x0,epsilon)
% INPUT
% ======================
% A ....... the positive definite matrix associated with the
% objective function
% b ....... a column vector associated with the linear part of the
% objective function
% x0 ...... starting point of the method
% epsilon . tolerance parameter



a=1;
A = [1 0; 0 a^2];
b=[0; 0];
x0= [2;1];

epsilon=1e-5;

x=x0;
iter=0;
grad=2*(A*x+b);

while (norm(grad,1)>epsilon)
iter=iter+1;
t=norm(grad)^2./(2*grad'*A*grad);
x=x-t*grad;
grad=2*(A*x+b);
fun_val=x'.*A.*x+a^2.*b'.*x;
fprintf("iter_number = %3d norm_grad = %2.6f fun_val = %2.6f\n",...
iter,norm(grad),fun_val);
end

%%Plotting
% The x and y-value range
 x = linspace(-5, 5, 100);
 y = linspace(-5, 5, 100);

 [X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);

 %Contour PLot
 figure

 %Quadratic function evaluation

 Z=X.^2+2*Y.^2;

 contour(X,Y,Z);
  colorbar;
  hold on;

  xlabel('x');
  ylabel('y');
  title('GM with line search for function')
```

[image: This is from the book]

[image: This is what I got]